# Android-With BeagleBoard

Tags: android, beagleboard

I am trying to boot android in beagleboard.anyone can explain step by step to boot android with beagle board.thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternatively, you can try 0xdroid: http://code.google.com/p/0xdroid/

0xdroid provides user-friendly installer along with new features.  Both rowboat and 0xdroid should help you.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to look at this : http://code.google.com/p/rowboat/. All the instructions are in the wiki tab.

Answer (score 0):

Try following link - Configure and Build Android on Beagle Board 
http://www.embeddedsystemonline.com/home/embedded-system/beagleboard-labs/lab5